# Agregar filas dinámicas a un tabla con datos extraídos de MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Mi pregunta es como puedo agregar los registros que me envía la búsqueda realizada en MYSQL desde PHP a una tabla HTML actualmente al dar clic en el botón buscar me arroja el resultado en la tabla pero si realizo otra búsqueda sustituye el registro por el nuevo.
Lo que necesito es que no se sustituya si no que se agregue debajo del primero que busco.

Este Codigo HTMl es el que utilizo para que se muestre los resultados.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cotizar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <div class="container">
                <header class="page-header">
                    <center>
                    <h1>TI SOLUCIONES</h1><small>Generador deCotizaciones</small>
                    </center>
                </header>


        <div class="form-inline">
            <form action="" method="POST" name="productos" class="panel-primary">
            <label class="h1">Codigo  </label>
            <input type="text" name="txtbuscar" id="buscarid" autocomplete="off">

        <button type="submit" name="consulta" id="consultaid" class="btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        </form>
      </div>


    <table class="table table-striped" id="idtabla1">
        <tr>
            <td>Cotizacion No.</td>
            <td>SKU</td>
            <td>Producto</td>
            <td>Descripcion</td>
            <td>Costo Unitario</td>
            <td>Cantidad</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>

    <?php

              foreach ((array)$resultado as $dato) {
                  echo "<tr><td>".$dato['Num_Cot']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$dato['SKU']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$dato['Producto_Nom']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$dato['Descripcion']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$dato['CostoUnitario']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>"."<input type='number' name='cantidad' id='contidadid'>"."</td>";
                  echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='total' id='totalid'>"."</td>";
                  "</tr>";
              }

    ?>
    </table>

    </div>


</html>
```

Y este es el PHP para realizar la búsqueda e insertar nuevos materiales

```
<?php

class modelo {


    private $db;
    private $productos;

    public  function __construct() {
        $this->db = conexion::conectar_db();
        $this->productos = array();

    }


    public function buscar_productos(){
        $buscar = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'txtbuscar');
        $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT Num_Cot, SKU, Producto_Nom, Descripcion, CostoUnitario FROM cotizacion WHERE SKU='$buscar' or Producto_Nom='$buscar'");

        while ($resultado = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

            $this->productos[] = $resultado;
        }

        return $this->productos;

    }

    public function insertar_productos(){
        $coti_num    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num_cot');
        $sku         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sku');
        $producto    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'producto');
        $descripcion = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'descripcion');
        $costo       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'costo');
        $existencia  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'existencia');
        $fecha       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fecha');
        $vendedor    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vendedor');

        try {

        $insertar = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO cotizacion (Num_Cot, SKU, Producto_Nom, Descripcion, CostoUnitario, Existencia, Fecha_Cot, Vendedor) "
            . "VALUES ('$coti_num', '$sku', '$producto', '$descripcion', '$costo', '$existencia', '$fecha', '$vendedor')");

        $registro = $this->db->real_query($insertar);

        return $registro == TRUE; 

        }

            catch (Exception $ex) {
            print "Error" .$ex->getMessage();
        }

        mysqli_close(Conexion::conectar_db());

    }
```

Y los que obtengo es lo siguiente al realizar la busqueda [image: Me arroja correctamente el resultado, pero al realizar otra busqueda sustituye los valores actuales por el nuevo]

¿Como puedo agregar más registros a la tabla sin que se sustituya el que ya esta?

Saludos a todos y gracias.

Comment: ¿quieres agregar las filas en tiempo real?

Comment: en tu variable de clase $this->productos te acumula el anterior y el nuevo. Verifica eso

Answer (score 1):

Solamente con PHP no creo que sea posible, ya que cada que ejecutas el script de tu busqueda las variables se pierden, veo varias soluciones pero tendrias que apoyarte de javascript

1.-Puedes realizar la busqueda por medio de AJAX y así en lugar de sustituir los resultados los vas añadiendo

2.-Otra aunque es más complicada, pudrias ir "guardando" las busquedas anteriores y al momento de buscar las ejecutas, pero es muy mala practica

Comment: Ok, voy a implementar AJAx, igual que tu había pensado en guardar las búsquedas y posteriormente llamarlas pero creo que mi base de datos crecería desmesuradamente. Otra Pregunta cual es la mejor manera para realizar la búsqueda con AJAX.

Comment: @leoshaka es un tanto amplia la pregunta de "cuál es la mejor forma". Pero encontrarás suficiente información cuando acá en el sitio o en la web en general. Por otro lado, su está respuesta solucionó tu problema, considera aceptarla